# Splitting specific polygons in a multipolygon in R

Tags: r, sf, segment

I am just starting to learn and apply the `sf` package for a spatial analytical problem.

I would like to divide the set of polygons (in the multipolygon geometry) into two groups-1 and 2 (randomly) identified by an indicator variable.
Next, keeping the group 1 polygons as they are, I would like to split each of the group 2 polygons into two.

````
library(sf)
nc <- read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"))
read_sf()->nc
nc|>
  select(SID79)|>
  plot(axes=FALSE)```
````

Creating a binary variable (for identifying the groups).

```
c <- runif(100)
for (i in 1:length(c)){
  if (c[i]<0.5){
    c[i] <- 0
  }
  else
    c[i] <- 1
  
}   

nc$indicator <- c
```

Now, how can I split only those polygons having indicator=1?

Note that there is no criteria for splitting. Any random segmentation is fine.

I initially thought nngeo's `st_segment` might be relevant but I cannot figure out how to identify the polygons based on the indicator.
Also, whether ToNoY's answer [here][1] could be adapted here perhaps?

Alternatively, how could I merge contiguous polygons having indicator=0 only? It would be similar to selecting a random subset of polygons and merge all the their neighbours with those. Would `st_touches` syntax be relevant here?

```
  [1]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67582/how-to-split-a-polygon-using-r
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you wan't polygon or multipolygon at the end but to divide the dataset in two according to your needs here is a solution :

```
library(sf)

nc <- read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"))

# add column with random indicator
nc$indicator <- round(runif(nrow(nc), 0, 1),0)

# split data frame
group0 <- nc[nc$indicator == 0, ]
group1 <- nc[nc$indicator == 1, ]
```

And another one in a tidy way :

```
nc <- nc |> 
   mutate(indicator = round(runif(nrow(nc), 0, 1),0))

group0 <- nc |> 
   filter(indicator == 0)
group1 <- nc |> 
   filter(indicator == 1)
```

Comment: Salut Paul. Thanks very much. I guess I wasn't clear. Might need some help in understanding the fundamentals. As I understand, the entire data frame is a multipolygon and each observation is a polygon right?

Comment: In fact, each row of nc dataset is a multipolygon with one or more polygon. You can see it by running `View(st_geometry(nc))`. 
If you want to convert MULTIPOLYGON to POLYGON you can do it with `st_cast(nc, "POLYGON")`

Comment: I see thanks a lot. C'est gentil! In fact, that was exactly was puzzling to me for some time. Is there any good reason why one would convert the constituent multipolygons to polygons? Asking because my next step is to create a group ID and merge some of the observations by the grouping variable (aggregating by group). Would conversion be relevant here? Merci

Comment: It depend on your work, for example if you have to find centroid for each polygon you will convert to POLYGON. For your r spatial journey I recommend you to read [Geocomputation with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/) which is very well constructed book.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Paul